# Banach algebra with left or right minimal ideal without minimal bi-ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra( or a ring). A left ideal $I$ of $A$ is called a left minimal ideal, if $I\neq\{0\}$ and there is no any other non-zero left ideal of $A$ completely lies in $I$. With a similar way right minimal ideal and minimal bi-ideal(two sided ideal) have been defined.

Is there a Banach algebra ( or a ring) which has left minimal ideal or right minimal ideal such that it does not have minimal bi-ideal?

Comment: The set of $n \times n$ matrices over a field is an example of this.

Comment: Could you please describe it ?! I mean why it does not have minimal bi- ideal?

Comment: For each subspace $V$ of $K^n$, there is a left ideal in $M_n(K)$ consisting of those matrices containing $V$ in their kernel, and a right ideal consisting of those matrices whose image is contained in $V$. It can be shown that these are the only left and right ideals. The result follows easily from this.

Comment: @Hamid The ring of matrices over a field has exactly two ideals: the whole ring and the zero ideal. It looks like your definition rules out the zero ideal, so unless you're willing to accept the whole ring as a minimal ideal, it does not have minimal ideals.

Comment: I need some ring or Banach algebra without minimal ideal with left or right minimal ideal. Unfortunately your Matrix algebra itself is its minimal ideal as @rschwieb  wrote. With the definition a minimal ideal can be whole ring or algebra.

Comment: I found a example for semigroup; If it can help to create a Banach algebra with that property::::::::: link

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDYQFjADahUKEwifv4Ob9-jGAhXKtxQKHYHsCEk&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprojecteuclid.org%2Fdownload%2Fpdf_1%2Feuclid.jmsj%2F1261153641&ei=_4CsVd_DN8rvUoHZo8gE&usg=AFQjCNGIC21DMTAHPq0wFzIVQrOZTLYLMg&sig2=iyOrGGOFhiCu5CyyMw97Pw&bvm=bv.98197061,d.d24

Answer (score 2):

This is example of a Banach algebra ( also a ring) that has not minimal ideal. But I don't have any idea that it has left or right minimal ideal . I found it from this [link](http://profsite.um.ac.ir/~moslehian/cfa/BA.HTM)

Let $\Delta=\{z\in \mathcal{C}| |z|\leq 1\}$. Suppose that $A(\Delta)$ be the set of all elements $C(\Delta)$ which are analytic on the interior of $\Delta$. $A(\Delta)$ is closed subalgebra of $C(\Delta)$. For any $n\geq0$ define $I_n=\{f\in A(\Delta)| f(0)=f^\prime(0)=f^{\prime\prime}(0)=\ldots=f^{(n)}=0\}$. $(I_n)_{n\geq0}$ is decreasing sequense of (primary) ideals. Now  if $J$ be a minimal ideal of $A(\Delta)$ then if $0\neq f\in J$ then $0\neq z^{n+1}f\in I_n\cap J$. So $I_n\cap J=J$. Hence $(\cap_{n=0}^\infty I_n)\cap J=J$. But $\cap_{n=0}^\infty I_n=\{0\}$ implies $J=\{0\}$ which is contradiction. So minimal ideal does not exists.